# How can I find information about the aircraft with registration / tail-number N58644?

Tags: aviation-history

I am trying to find information on aircraft N58644 which doesn't show on the N number listing. This is a BT-13A converted to civilian use from the 40s or 50s. Any ideas where I can get any information since the FAA doesn't show it?

Comment: I guess it means that it's not a valid registration, FAA.gov [says it's not assigned/reserved](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Results.aspx?NNumbertxt=58644) or it just got assigned

Comment: Can you give some more details about where you've seen or read about that N number? It doesn't show up on [this site](http://www.warbirdregistry.org/bt13registry/bt13registry.html) either, for example.

Comment: Even if it were a total loss, the plane should still be listed in the FAA registry...  You could also try contacting the NTSB if you are sure that is the tail number.  Perhaps it was in an accident but somehow it wasn't logged in the FAA database...  You wouldn't be able to search that online because they only go back to the mid 90's.  But you can contact the main office.

Answer (score 7):

I have checked the 01 July 1965 FAA register, and it does not show there. My father had a BT-13A N61907, and it doesn't show either. The usual fate of postwar BT's was sale to crop duster companies; they were of value only for their R-985 engines and 2D30 props to be fitted on Stearman dusters or airshow planes. The airframes were scrapped.

If you can convince someone at FAA OKC, they could call up their archives (in Ft. Worth IIRC) and get the answer you seek.